# MVC multiple parameter routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been trying to pull the parameters passed into a page so I can post it back in Context.

So far,

```
        ViewBag.Message = string.Format("{0}::{1}::{2}",
        RouteData.Values["controller"],
        RouteData.Values["actions"],
        RouteData.Values["id"]);
```

works with anything simple like "66" or "tt" but anything more complex like "?name=blargh?viewId=66" and it fails.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to see if I could strike gold but nothing seems to work so does anybody have any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong/should be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " but anything more complex like "?name=blargh?viewId=66" and it fails.

This doesn't seem to be routing information but query string which you should retrieve from the `Request.QueryString` bag.

If the `{id}` parameter is part of your route (as the default routes `{controller}/{action}/{id}`) I hope you realize that this `id` cannot be anything you like just because there are rules for an url. For example it cannot contain `?` because this symbol has an entirely different meaning in an url - it represents the query string separator.

Comment: Thanks I new there must of been something I was missing, once the accept timer runs out or on monday I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Yeah I was only setting it up to work on both just in case although I should only need to work with parameters, additionally do you know of good site that I should be able to further learn about routing and hoping a way to separate each query key so I wouldn't just be producing a single long url string.